# Native screen recording issue (Shift+Ctrl+Alt+R)

Tags: video

I wanted to use the built-in screen recorder to record how to do an installation but the recording terminates during different portions of the install application.

Example:

- Begin screen recording on a Live USB viewing the desktop
- Click Install Ubuntu 17.10
- Screen recorder terminates

The screen recorder also terminates after whether choosing to download updates or choosing to install third party applications screen.

Also terminates after choosing a security key for installing an encrypted install.

Not sure where to report this bug as the screen recorder shouldn't terminate unless explicitly commanded to do so.

I tried on my currently installed system, and the recorder dies when I umounted/mounted a drive.

Seems to be where the issue lies.

Comment: Ask Ubuntu is not a normal forum. Please add answers in the answers section below rather than in your question. Please don't put "SOLVED" in the title of your question. Instead, click the check mark next to an answer that solves the question.

Answer (score 0):

The questioner, Duck Dude, added this answer to the question:

> Not a bug: native screencast lasts for a maximum of 30s

Comment: The length can be adjusted in dconf (dconf-editor > org->gnome->settings-daemon->plugins->media-keys > max-screencast-length) or thru gsettings command `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys max-screencast-length  XXX` where XXX is value in seconds